# Maximal independent set of size exactly k in interval graphs

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, computability-theory

I am interested in the following decision problem. Given an interval graph $G$ and a $k\in\mathbb{N}$, is there a maximal independent set (independent dominating set) of size exactly $k$ ?

Interval graphs are a subclass of chordal graphs and it is known that this problem is NP-complete for chordal graphs.

It is also known that the problem, is there an independent dominating set of size $\leq k$, is polynomial for interval graphs and even for chordal graphs.

My question is if the stated problem is NP-complete. If this is known, i would be very thankful for a reference.